# Ansible - How do I access each entry's lists of values?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I've created this using **set_fact** but in my next task, I need to loop over each schema entry and grab its list of values

```
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": {
    "MYSCHEMA1": [
        "person_view.sql",
        "address_view.sql"
    ],
    "MYSCHEMA2": [
        "person_view.sql",
        "address_view.sql"
    ],
    "MYSCHEMA3": [
        "person_view.sql",
        "address_view.sql"
    ],
    "MYSCHEMA4_": [
        "person_view.sql",
        "address_view.sql"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice piece of documentation about [loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-hashes):

```
with_dict: "{{ myschemas }}"
```